# how to find the mode of a set of numbers in a square matrix

Tags: c

I have this code I'm trying to find the mode of the numbers in a matrix but the output on the mode part is always 0 even when the matrix has no zero number in it. However i'm unsure how to go about this. this is what i have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int mode(int a[],int n) {
    int maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (a[j] == a[i])
                ++count;
        }

        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = a[i];
        }
    }        
    return maxValue;
}

int main(){
    int row, column,mat[100][100],maximum=0,minimum,sum =0,a=0,n=0,i, j;// int i and j are loop variables
    float Average,x;
    printf("Enter number of rows (between 1 and 100): ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter number of columns (between 1 and 100): ");
    scanf("%d", &column);

    printf("\nEnter elements of the matrix:\n");

    for(i=0; i<row; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<column; ++j)
        {
            printf("Enter element a%d%d: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\nThe elements in the matrix are: \n\n") ;
        for(i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
            for(j = 0 ; j < column ; j++){
                printf("%d", mat[i][j]) ;//displays the square matrix
                printf("\t");
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<row; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<column; ++j){
            if ( mat[i][j] < minimum ){
                minimum = mat[i][j];
            }
            if ( mat[i][j] > maximum ){
                maximum = mat[i][j];
            }
            sum = sum + mat[i][j];
            x = row * column;
            Average = sum /x;
        }
    printf("Maximum element in the matrix is %d\n", maximum);
    printf("Minimum element in the matrix is %d\n", minimum);
    printf("The sum of the elements in the matrix is %d\n",sum);
    printf("The average of the elements in the matrix is %.4f\n",Average);
    printf("Mode = %d ", mode(a,n));

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Enter number of rows (between 1 and 100): 3
Enter number of columns (between 1 and 100): 3

Enter elements of the matrix:
Enter element a11: 4
Enter element a12: 4
Enter element a13: 4
Enter element a21: 5
Enter element a22: 6
Enter element a23: 7
Enter element a31: 8
Enter element a32: 9
Enter element a33: 0


The elements in the matrix are:

4       4       4
5       6       7
8       9       0
Maximum element in the matrix is 9
Minimum element in the matrix is 0
The sum of the elements in the matrix is 47
The average of the elements in the matrix is 5.2222
Mode = 4
```

Comment: 1) Format this mess. 2) Learn [ask] and provide the necessary information. 3) The debugger is your friend.

Comment: You declare `a` as an int in main with `int a = 0;`, then pass it to your function (without chaging that value anywhere): `mode(a, n)`, but that function is expecting an `int *` as first parameter (it doesn't matter that you called it `a` too).

Comment: Besides, you are calculating `x = row * column; Average = sum /x;` for every element in the array. Move that outside the two nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

The Argument should be a matrix rather than an integer variable i suppose

```
printf("Mode = %d ", mode(a,n));
```